# Prove that $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n, (1 + |\xi|^2)^s d\xi$

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, convolution

> I would like to show that $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in the space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n, (1 + |\xi|^2)^s d \xi)$ (here, $s$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{R}$).

I am familiar with the standard argument that if $\phi \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n),$ $\int \phi = 1$, $\phi_\epsilon = \epsilon^{-n} \phi (\epsilon^{-1}( \cdot))$ and $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n, d \xi)$, then each $f \ast \phi_{\epsilon} \in C^\infty$ with $f \ast \phi_{\epsilon} \to f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n, d \xi)$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

I am wondering if this same style of argument can be used to prove density in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n, (1 + |\xi|^2)^s d \xi)$? If we try to reproduce the old argument verbatim, then we run into a bit of trouble because the factor $(1 + |\xi|^2)^s$ now lies inside the integral, and it's not quite clear to me how to define convolution in the setting of this more general measure space $L^2( \mathbb{R}^n, (1 + |\xi|^2)^s d \xi)$.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** 
A possible approach is to use the fact that the [Schwartz space $\mathcal S(\mathbb{R})$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), the space of functions all of whose derivatives are rapidly decreasing, **is dense in** $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n, (1 + |\xi|^2)^s d \xi)$ (*recall that a rapidly decreasing function is essentially a function $f(\cdot)$ such that $f'(\cdot), f''(\cdot),f'''(\cdot), \ldots ,$ all exist everywhere on $\Bbb R$ and go to zero as $x → ±∞$ faster than any inverse power of $x$*) and that this space $\mathcal S(\mathbb{R})$ **is a subspace** of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, giving the desired density.

Here is a related [link](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-103-fourier-analysis-theory-and-applications-spring-2004/lecture-notes/lec_16.pdf).